# Printing none in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have the following code to calculate the output of each layer in Keras.
When I run the below code None is printed in the output.

```
 single_layer_mem=1
 output_shape=model.layers[1].output.shape
 trainable_count=model.layers[1].count_params()

 for s in output_shape:
     if s is None:
         continue
     single_layer_mem *= s

 total_memory = 4*(5*single_layer_mem+ trainable_count )
 print(total_memory)
```

The formula for calculating total memory required by DNN model is as follows:

```
total_memory = 4 * (batch_size * memory + trainable_count + non_trainable_count)
```

I would like to confirm:

- If I have to calculate per layer memory requirement or output data size
- If above code I have written is correct or not.

Comment: What are the contents of model?  Can you show your actual output?

Comment: I have sorted out this issue due to the ? in the output shape iteration was not being performed, I changed it to this line of code it's now working result=model.layers[1].output_shape[1:]. Thanks alot for your wonderful help @z242